# How to fix the footer to bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, image, footer, bottom-up

I want to fixed a image to bottom relate with size of monitoring. I
want to show in just main page.

```
<div class="no-footer" align="right"> 
  <a class="btn text-danger" style="margin-bottom:5px; width:100px; " href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")">About</a> 
  <p class="bottom" align="center"> <img src="~/media/images/bb9.png" /> </p> 
  <hr style="left:0; right: 0; bottom:200px; height: 200px; position:absolute;" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: What is your HTML and CSS?

Comment: <div class="no-footer" align="right">
            <a class="btn text-danger" style="margin-bottom:5px; width:100px; " href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")">About</a>
            <p class="bottom" align="center">
                <img src="~/media/images/bb9.png" />
            </p>
            <hr style="left:0; right: 0; bottom:200px; height: 200px; position:absolute;" />
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

```
.fotter
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
```

[Refer here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/bottom-footer-demo.htm)

Comment: it's not a footer at all but just the image that I want to always at the bottom of main page.

Comment: so in `<img ` call `class="fotter"` with above code

Comment: <div class="no-footer" align="right">
            <a class="btn text-danger" style="margin-bottom:5px; width:100px; " href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")">About</a>
            <p class="bottom" align="center">
                <img src="~/media/images/bb9.png" />
            </p>
            <hr style="left:0; right: 0; bottom:200px; height: 200px; position:absolute;" />
        </div>

Comment: I think `footer` would be meaningful than `fotter`.